# iOS Swift sharing PDF file, then delete

Tags: ios, swift, sharing

I have a question regarding sharing pdf files in swift. Sharing is quite simple and it already works in my app. I receive pdf file from backend, save it to local variable as bytes array, than save it in app cache directory and pass to UIActivityViewController.

Is there any way to receive some callback, that sharing action has been completed, or canceled, so I can immediately remove file from cache?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u could clean your cache when dismissing your UIActivityViewController

Comment: You mean by using completer? I’ll check that if the file will last long enough to be successfully shared.

Comment: yeah i meant that in completion block u can implement your logic

Comment: I've tried and it works. Thanks a lot fot Your help.
Anyway i found other way to do it too.
You can save in variable bytes array as Data, which can be passed directly to UIActivityViewController and then there is no need to save the file in cache.
Anyway this way is not the best way, because there is no possibility to set any file name.

Comment: i am glad that it helped)

Answer (score 0):

`UIActivityViewController` provides a `completionWithItemsHandler` property to  handle this situation

```swift
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activityType, userTakeAnyAction, returnedItems, error in
    // Clean file here
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
}
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
```